# Make helix bent into a circle have same thickness everywhere

Tags: path, splines

[image: helix bent into 360 degrees]

Here is the ring I made. I bent (simple deform modifier) a helix by 360 degrees. The helix works right and is the same thickness everywhere, but this is not also true for the bent ring.

I tried to use different methods such spinning it with another spline, but I get the same result every time.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: https://we.tl/t-FIcfVqSG58

Comment: wetransfer link - this is the .blend file above

Comment: i am pretty sure it can be done via geometry nodes. unfortunately i am too dumb to make it...i can make it with a simple circle:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRwcN.jpg. but i cannot get the right rotation for a spiral...but i am sure Robin can do it ;)

Answer (score 6):

You could create a segment with a *Screw* modifier, then create an empty:

[image]

Give your object an *Array* modifier with the empty as *Object Offset*, move and rotate the empty untill it makes a complete circle:

[image]

Edit the object so that the segments stick to each other:

[image]

Comment: Niiiiiiice!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks, I hope it answers. I love the Simple Deform modifier but you can't avoid deformation with it, so Array is a solution

Comment: i tried to make an answer using curves, and bevels and lost an hour on it. this works much better :D

Comment: @Jachym Michal oh yes I didn't try with curve bevel... Edit: Ok but as soon as you bend it 360° you probably have the same problem